# Jquery - Elements Value Check then Slide Form UP

Tags: jquery, select, input, slide

I'm trying to modify a form that i've made earlier ...
Which has the particularity to slide up another form, soon as the first is confirmed.

Now i need to add one extra function to check the elements values,
before the "CONFIRM" function is executed.

Here his the ["FIDDLE"](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyber_Coder/5a5hedao/) of the first function ...
(Press "RUN", if it does nothing)

Now what i've i done to accomplish my attempt in the extra function;

```
// MY PROBLEM is in here
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.Confirm-UP').click(function(e) {
    var isValid = true;
    $('input[type="text"].required').each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            isValid = false;
            $(this).css({
                "box-shadow": "0 0 7px #D11919"
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({
                "box-shadow": ""
            });
        }
    });
    if (isValid == false) 
        e.preventDefault();

// Button Click Check Selectors
 if ($("#UsrAr")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
           isValid = false;
            $("#UsrAr").css({
                "box-shadow": "0 0 7px #D11919"
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#UsrAr").css({
                "box-shadow": ""
            });
        }
    });
    if (isValid == false) 
        e.preventDefault();
    else 
        $('.FORM2').animate({
      top: '-202px'
    }, 1000);
});
// Button Click send FORM to BACK
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Back').click(function() {
    $('.FORM2').animate({
      top: '0px'
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

and here's the ["FIDDLE"](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyber_Coder/uvh4rapv/) of the full work, of my attempt
(Press "RUN", if it does nothing)

Please can someone help me in this... Thanks

Comment: Your first fiddle doesn't work because your javascript doesn't have a "Confirm()" function anywhere in it. And you have click handlers for something with a class="sl5b-UP" but there is nothing in your html with that class.

Comment: The second doesn't work because again you have onclick="confirm();" but you don't have a confirm() function anywhere in your javascript so an error is thrown. If you check the javascript console you can see these things.

Comment: That is weird, i've check and the Fiddles where UpDATED... That was really weird!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some closing brackets out of place and you have onclick="Confirm()" in your html but no confirm function. I removed the onclick from the html and moved your closing brackets down to the bottom where they belong. I also commented out an e.preventDefault because you were already doing it at the bottom where it belonged.

Check the comments in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uvh4rapv/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Confirm-UP').click(function(e) {
        console.log(".confirm-up clicked")
        var isValid = true;
        $('input[type="text"].required').each(function() {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                isValid = false;
                $(this).css({
                    "box-shadow": "0 0 7px #D11919"
                });
            }
            else {
                $(this).css({
                    "box-shadow": ""
                });
            }
        });


       // COMMENTED THIS OUT BECAUSE YOU"RE DOING THE e.preventDefault BELOW
       //if (isValid == false)     
       //    e.preventDefault();

// Button Click Check Selectors
     if ($("#UsrAr")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
               isValid = false;
                $("#UsrAr").css({
                    "box-shadow": "0 0 7px #D11919"
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#UsrAr").css({
                    "box-shadow": ""
                });
            }
       //}); COMMENTED OUT THESE SHOULD BE BELOW  
        if (isValid == false){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            console.log('no errors found')
            $('.FORM2').animate({
              top: '-200px'
            }, 1000);
        }
    }); // THIS IS WHERE THE CLICK HANDLER SHOULD END
});
```

Comment: You are the best ... Truly the best ... And that was a really fast answer, thanks